# how to find the range of exact word repeated in the string (case sensitive)

Tags: swift, string, range

I want to find the nsrange of the the word which is repeating in the string ,it search should be case sensitive .

for example :

the main string is let str = "Hi satheesh how are you doing ,Hellow satheesh1 did you find the answer for satheesh".

now I want to find the ranges of  word "satheesh" ..expected nsrange count should be 2 .i.e [nsrange(location : 3, lenght : 8),[nsrange(other word satheesh)] it should not take the range of satheesh1 because satheesh != satheesh1 .

I am using below code

```
extension String {
func ranges(of substring: String, options: CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) -> [Range<Index>] {
    var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
    while let range = self.range(of: substring, options: options, range: (ranges.last?.upperBound ?? self.startIndex)..<self.endIndex, locale: locale) {
        ranges.append(range)
    }
    return ranges
}
}
```

but the problem with this code is when finding the range it considering satheesh == satheesh1 so I am getting the ranges of satheesh and satheesh.

Can some one help me out to solve this problem

Comment: What happens if the string is like this "hi satheesh." Ending in a fullstop?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri it end up with space

Comment: Should it be counted or not?

Comment: not required only range of all satheesh in string  but it should not take the range of satheesh1

Comment: The word “you” is also repeated in your example sentence, should it be taken into consideration?

Comment: @Carpsen90 no i will have one search string for example satheesh ,only range of satheesh it should consider

Comment: You can use a regex

Comment: @LeoDabus any example code pls

Comment: @RakeshaShastri thanks for your time ,that was good try

Comment: What happened to Martin and Leo's answers?